# The same declaration in a different order produce different results in gcc

Tags: c, file-io

The problem is in line 7: `int ret=3, x, y;`

if I declare the y first (like the line 8) the result will be
different

on my computer right now is printing only the Y values​​, with this
change in the declaration goes to print only the values ​​of X

## Makefile

```
gcc -g -o open_file_test open_file_test.c;
./pen_file_test input
```

## CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int worldsize = 0;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int ret=3, x, y;
    //int ret=3, y, x;
    char chr;
    int teste;

    FILE * inputFile;
    inputFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    teste = fscanf(inputFile,"%d", &worldsize);
    printf("Tamanho: %d\n", worldsize);

    while(1){
        ret=fscanf(inputFile,"%d %d %s\n", &x, &y, &chr);
        if(ret != 3)
            break;
        printf("x: %d  y: %d\n", x, y);
    }
    printf("End File :D\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## input_file

> ```
> 10
> 1 0 w
> 2 1 s
> 6 9 w
> 3 7 w
> 5 0 s
> 1 5 t
> 1 5 t
> 7 5 t
> 9 7 t
> 9 3 t
> 0 0 i
> ```

## output

> ```
> Tamanho: 10
> x: 0  y: 0
> x: 0  y: 1
> x: 0  y: 9
> x: 0  y: 7
> x: 0  y: 0
> x: 0  y: 5
> x: 0  y: 5
> x: 0  y: 5
> x: 0  y: 7
> x: 0  y: 3
> x: 0  y: 0
> End File :D
> ```

On my computer only read the Y, and the same code on my colleague
computer only reads X, and in another friend's computer works fine
(read the X and Y), can somebody explain the reason?

Comment: What are the versions of gcc in each case? Are you sure the source files are otherwise identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour in your code here:

```
fscanf(inputFile,"%d %d %s\n", &x, &y, &chr);
```

Reading a string into `chr` which is a single `char` variable.  Even if the string contains a single character, a null-terminator will be written after it.  This may well be spilling into your integers on the stack.

If you want a single char, then use `%c`:

```
fscanf(inputFile,"%d %d %c\n", &x, &y, &chr);
```

If you prefer a string, then make `chr` a `char` array large enough to hold any potential string (plus a null terminator).  Alternatively, use `fgets` to read a line at a time and then parse the values out later.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
ret=fscanf(inputFile,"%d %d %s\n", &x, &y, &chr);
```

Your `fscanf` format has `%s`, which means "String" *(several characters, ending with a NULL-terminator)*, but the matching variable for the data, `chr` is only a single character, and cannot handle multiple characters.

To fix it, I recommend using formatter `%c` *(which means a single character)* instead of `%s`.